# Best practices for running ICs with 12V vs 5V rails

Tags: led, power, integrated-circuit, power-electronics, mosfet-driver

I'm working on a circuit that needs 12V to trigger high-power LEDs (via a Power FET).  However, to accomplish this, I also need a variety of ICs; right now I have a TC4427 for driving the FET's gate, a 556 for one-shot pulse generation, and a ATtiny84 to trigger the 556.

The FET Driver and 556 can both run off a VCC as high as 12V; only the microcontroller requires a voltage as low as 5V.

Right now my plan is to power the driver and pulse generator with a 12 volt VCC (with 0.1uF film + 4.7uF electrolytic bypass caps), and use a small 200-300 mA switching regulator like an ADP1111 to provide a small 5V rail for the microcontroller.

Is this good practice?

I only expect the FET / LED to be powered on ~1% of the time, 5% maximum; I presume this means that the 556 and TC4427 should have very low power draw most of the time.

My other options:

- Use a linear regulator like a 7805.  I'm concerned the FET Driver will need enough current at 5V that the regulator will get quite hot.
- Use a beefier buck converter than the ADP1111 to provide a 5V / 1-2A rail.  I'm trying to avoid SMD parts at the moment, but this is an acceptable solution.

I'm a bit new to figuring out good power management, and would appreciate any advice as to how to best practices for dealing with ICs that can accept a variety of supply voltages.

Comment: That's still a bit soon to tell whether its a good practice or not.. There are many ways to implement what you propose, many being good practices and others most probably not.. But yeah, a switching IC is viable and better if you expect the load to be significant.. that said, the FET driver will need current in a low duty cycle, so you might be fine with a 7805 or a more modern alternative..

Comment: Good point.  I edited the post to add that I expect the LEDs (and thus the FET, FET Driver, and Pulse Generator) to be on about 1%-5% of the time; the duty cycle is low enough that maybe a linear regulator is fine and the switching power supply is overkill.

Comment: Are you on batteries? How much does power matter?

Comment: As a matter of best practices, get rid of the 556. Use something like a 74HC4538. Much better pulse stability, and requires fewer components for one-shot operation.

Comment: @Reinderien Power doesn't matter; I'm more worried about the heat from the LM7805 causing damage to the circuit than I am about conserving power, though I guess I could use a heatsink.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Fair point; I've been thinking about using a 74HC123 or similar; just haven't gotten around to getting my hands on one and testing it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice to deal with mixed power rails like this project is to leave the high-voltage (12V) for LEDs, and feed every IC from 3.3 or 5V using switching DC-DC converter. To save troubles with things like high-current loops, inductors etc, I would recommend "linear replacements" like [RECOM](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/recom-power/R-78E5.0-0.5/945-1648-5-ND/2834904) or [Murata modules](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Murata-Power-Solutions/OKI-78SR-5-15-W36-C). These modules are not cheap, but will save you a lot of efforts. eBay can also help if the budget is really tight.

Answer (score 0):

No offense intended, but your proposed circuit sounds very convoluted so I don't think I would ascribe 'best practice' to it.

If you are going to use an ATtiny84, use one of the four built in PWM channels to drive a logic level FET to control the LEDs. That is all that is required.

Comment: This is a comment not an answer.

Comment: The ATtiny's PWM driver can't output enough current to drive a beefy power FET like an IRF540; you *need* a gate driver to be able to switch those fast.  I also need the LEDs to be driven in ~150 microsecond pulses precisely, regardless of how frequently it's driven.  It's a lot harder to program the PWM channel to do that than it is to just set up a one-shot pulse generator.

Comment: There are many high speed, logic level FETs from which you may select. Take a look at the MTP50P03HDLG, for example. Programming a PWM channel is less than a dozen lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fylkfe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The ATtiny84 needs only about 2mA at several MHz, and it works with any supply voltage from 1.8V to 5V. You can even use a simple two-resistor voltage divider to power that thing from 12V.

If your FET driver is designed correctly, it will draw no power at all from the 5V rail, just sink it.

Uh, and why do you have a NE556 impulse former? Don't you trust your programming skills?